# Что значит часть кода в Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Мне не понятна часть кода, связанная с роутером в Laravel

```
Route::get('/about', ['as' => 'about', 'uses' => 'FrontendController@about'])
```

Вопрос конкретно о том, что значит `'as' => 'about'` и `'uses' =>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
'as' => 'about'
```

Это уникальное имя роута, нужно для того чтобы можно было потом например выполнять переадресацию на него `redirect()->route('profile');`. Это повышает гибкость приложения, чтобы не надо было везде искать по шаблонам и менять `url`, в случае его смены.

```
'uses' => 'FrontendController@about'
```

`uses` - Как раз и указывает на то, чтобы использовать `контроллер@метод`. Ведь в ларавел можно выполнять и анонимные функции:

```
Route::get('/about', ['as' => 'about', function(){ ... }]);
```

---

Документация по роутингу, почитайте, там интересно :)

http://laravel.su/docs/5.4/routing

Answer (score 1):

Это выражение можно перевести на стандартный, Где это:

```
Route::get('/about', ['as' => 'about', 'uses' => 'FrontendController@about'])
```

Значит это:

```
Route::get('/about', 'FrontendController@about')->name('about');
```